# I am trying to divide two variables in jQuery:

Tags: jquery, html

You can go through the code in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amarkoppal/jqvabtyr/1/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#product').change(function() {
  $('#result').text($(this).val() * 6);
});

$('#product1').change(function() {
  var num1 = $('#result');
  var num2 = $('#product1');
  var result1 = parseFloat(num1, 10) / parseFloat(num2, 10);
  $("#result1").text(result1);
  console.log(typeof(result1));
 });
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="col-xs-6">
  Count<input name="shares" id="product" type="number" / min="0">
 </div>
</div>

<div>
  Total Value: <span id="result"></span>/
  <input name="shares1" id="product1" type="number" / min="0">
  <br /> Final Result: <span id="result1"></span>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When I try to divide two variables I'm getting `NaN` in the result field.

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You are parsing the jquery object, not its value/text.

```
  var num1 = $('#result').text();
  var num2 = $('#product1').val();
```

[Internally](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.3), parseFloat will try to convert the passed argument as a string first. So over that object `toPrimitive` will be called and its default primitive value will be returned. For example : `"[object object]"`. So when converting a non numeric string will leads to `NaN`. Hence `NaN/NaN` is eqauls to `NaN`

Answer (score 1):

```
num1 = $("#result");
```

Here, num1 is an array of element. To parse the content you have to replace this with:

```
num1 = $("#result")[0].innerHTML;
```

Same with num2:

```
num2 = $("#product1")[0].value;
```

Or use the jQuery shortcuts:

```
num1 = $("#result").text();
num2 = $("#product1").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

use:
You need to properly receive data first.

.text() for span and .val() for input box.

```
var num1 = $('#result').text();
var num2 = $('#product1').val();
```